# Continuity of operators in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $H=L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $U_tf(x) = f(x-t)$.
I want to prove that $t \rightarrow U_tf$ is continuous in $H$ and $t\rightarrow U_t$ is not continuous in $B(H)$.

I can't estimate $||U_tf - U_sf||_{L^2(\mathbb R)}$. In the continuity of $U_t$ I need some counterexample, I can't think of any though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to consider the case $t=0$ (then $U_0=I=\text{identity}$.) We need to estimate
$$
\|I-U_t\|_{B(H)}=\sup_{\|f\|_H\le1}\|f-U_tf\|_H.
$$
For fixed $t>0$, take $f\in H$ with compact support in an interval of length smaller than $t$. The the supports of $f$ and $U_tf$ are disjoint, and
$$
\|f-U_tf\|_H^2=\int_{\Bbb R}|f(x)-f(x-t)|^2\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R}|f(x)|^2\,dx+\int_{\Bbb R}|f(x-t)|^2\,dx=2\|f\|_H^2.
$$
It follows that $\|I-U_t\|_{B(H)}\ge\sqrt2$, while $\|I\|_{B(H)}=1$.

Comment: Thank you. What if we wanted to check continuity in $t>0$? $t \rightarrow U_t$ is not linear so checking continuity in one point is not sufficient. What about the first part?

Comment: For $t\ne0$ write $\|(U_t-U_s)f\|^2$ and do a change of variable to reduce it the $t=0$ case.

Comment: I thought you knew how to do the first part. It's been asked here lots of times. Prove it first for continuous functions with compact support and then use a density argument.